# How to make default time zone apply in Spring Boot Jackson Date serialization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I have configured my Spring Boot application to serialize dates as ISO8601 strings:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

This is what I am getting:

```
"someDate": "2017-09-11T07:53:27.000+0000"
```

However my time zone is Europe/Madrid. In fact if I print `TimeZone.getDefault()` that's what I get.

How can I make Jackson serialize those datetime values using the actual timezone? GMT+2

```
"someDate": "2017-09-11T09:53:27.000+0200"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved registering a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer bean:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonObjectMapperCustomization() {
    return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> 
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.timeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
}
```

Comment: Hello, after adding this config and use @JsonFormat annotation with specific pattern it does not seem to find the default timezone:

`@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 37):

I found myself with the same problem. 
In my case, I have only one timezone for my app, then adding:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone: America/Sao_Paulo
```

in my `application.properties` solved the problem.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#JACKSON

Answer (score 32):

You can set timezone for whole application with adding this to a config class:

```
@PostConstruct
void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Comment: Jackson won't pick that up. The default TimeZone is the right one. My solution solves it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @codependent I use jackson in my project too and this configuration solved my problem for time zones. Anyway if you solve your problem, nothing to argue :) I will just leave my post if anybody can use it. Happy coding.

Comment: yes this will work, it depends where in your application you are setting default time zone. this work's good because now ur application will not do any time adjustment.

Comment: This sets the "target" timezone of (de)serialization, while the `JsonFormat(timezone = "xxx")` sets the input timezone of (de)serialization when parsing as well as formating. See [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322376/simpledateformat-with-timezone-set-gets-correct-value-but-wrong-zone?noredirect=1#answer-53337257) for details.

Comment: @barbakini solution solved my problem. In my case I save OffsetDateTimes on database as offset "+00:00" (or "Z"), and when retrieving them, the applicaiton automatically added the offset. With this setting it doesn't.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

**There are 2 solutions for this:**

**1. Add JSON format annotation**

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")
private Date insertionTime;
```

**2.  Add Jackson time zone to properties (spring boot)**

```
spring.jackson.time-zone: America/Sao_Paulo
```

**Reference :**  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates