# SimpleDateFormat with Timezone set gets correct value but wrong zone

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, java-8, jackson-databind

I have a simple test in a Spring application, which has default timezone set to `UTC`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MemberIntegrationApp {

    @Autowired
    private TimeZoneProperties timeZoneProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneProperties.getAppDefault()));  // which is UTC
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MemberIntegrationApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

And, this simple test: (**The test class is annotated with `@SpringBootTest` to load the configuration in main class and `@SpringRunner` is applied, too**)

```
/**
 * Test the effect of setting timezone
 */
@Test
public void testTimezoneSettingOnSimpleDateFormat() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String d = "2018-08-08 12:34:56";
    log.info("Trying to parse the date string: {}", d);
    Date result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 12:34 UTC: {}", result);

    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 12:34 UTC: {}", result);

    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 10:34 CEST: {}", result);
    log.info("Now the offset(depre): {}", result.getTimezoneOffset());
}
```

I have output:

```
Trying to parse the date string: 2018-08-08 12:34:56
The result should be 12:34 UTC: Wed Aug 08 12:34:56 UTC 2018
The result should be 12:34 UTC: Wed Aug 08 12:34:56 UTC 2018
The result should be 10:34 CEST: Wed Aug 08 10:34:56 UTC 2018
Now the offset(depre): 0
```

Now, why the fourth line has the value correct, but the timezone is wrong? It should be `Europe/Madrid`. And the offset(which is deprecated in Java 8, OK I can forgive it), it should be +0200, not 0.

It is UTC because when converting to string in `log.info()`, slf4j is interferring???? Or what? I don't think so because `System.out.println()` gives me UTC too.

I know I should use `OffsetDateTime`, but it is legacy and we cannot change all fields of date to that, for now. I want to know why Java parsed it wrongly.

What is the effect of `Timezone.getDefault()` when parsing with SimpleDateFormat? And what is that of `f.getTimezone()`? They seem to act in different part of the process.....

I ask this question, because internally Jackson uses `SimpleDateFormat` to process date string/formatting dates. Does the config on an `ObjectMapper` affect the `SimpleDateFormat` that the mapper uses?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For one thing java.time is much less confusing when it comes to conversion between time zones.

Comment: Ye... but it is not me, but Spring/Jackson... you know.

Comment: [FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug, but rather a misinterpretation of the lines:

```
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 10:34 CEST: {}", result);
```

What does it mean ?

You first set a time zone, telling the parser you are about to parse a time in Europe/Madrid zone.

Then you display it. It cannot guess in which time zone you want it, so it displays it in the default time zone, UTC in your case.

---

Note that:

- it's actually 10:34 in UTC while it's 12:34 in Madrid, and not the other way round.
- `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` is the [offset between UTC and the default timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (thus 0 in your case), nothing to do with the time zone you used to configure the parser. Moreover it is deprecated since java 1.1, you should not really use it anymore.

To display a date value in different time zone, `SimpleDateFormat.format()` can be used, for instance:

```
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    log.info("UTC {}", f.format(new Date()));
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    log.info("Europe/Madrid {}", f.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Yes I was wrong, you got me; so this is like `input(as f.getTimezone()) ----> f ---->date(as default timezone)`, not the other way around. It is that when parsing, `f.setTimezone()` establishes the input timezone of the string, and the default timezone establishes the output date timezone. So, when doing this in Spring Boot, it is the same? How about formatting?

Comment: So, in the first case, we know that if the timezone is not set, the formatter will take UTC as preset, right?

Comment: Yes. To output a date in a different time zone, see my update

Comment: The key point to understand is that `Date` is really **a point in time**, and therefore has no inherent time zone or offset. It's only when you want to parse or print a date that you have to wonder in which zone you are

Comment: Right, `Date` is a point of time and its `getTimezoneOffset()` method has been deprecated since Java 1.1, with a pointer to `Calendar`, which was the correct tool before Java 8’s `java.time` API…

Comment: But when we examine it with debugger, we actually see a property `zoneInfo`  of any `java.util.Date` and when we print it we see `CET`, `IST`, etc, and the offset is good and correct. I would say that the timezone is present always, although somehow hidden; I used `getTimezoneOffset()` above knowing it is deprecated, so I put `depre` in the comment; just wanted to show that the object has that part of information. Actually, if it does not, the formatter cannot do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply; in the OP I was thinking of this line but put it wrong:

```
 log.info("The result should be 14:34 CEST: {}", result);
```

I thought it is like "So I want it to be Madrid so the output is Madrid timezone", but is the opposite:

**The timezone of the formatter will be the input date/string's timezone, while the default timezone(if not changed, that of the JVM, if changed, the value of `Timezone.getDefault()`, will be the output result(date/string)'s timezone. Based on these two, the formatter will do the conversion.**

**And, Spring/Jackson internally uses `SimpleDateFormat` to do JSON/Object serialization/deserialization, so it will be the rule for Spring, too**

**And, as I test, `spring.jackson.time-zone` and `mapper.setTimezone()` will be overridden by `JsonFormat(timezone = "xxx")` on the fields. That is to say, the `spring.jackson.time-zone` is more general and applies to all fields of Date who needs an "input" timezone, and `JsonFormat(timezone = "xxx")` is more specific and overrides the former one.** I guess `spring.jackson.dateformat` and `@JsonFormat(pattern = "xx")` have the same relationship but I haven't tested.

Graphically:

[image]

I write this test to demonstrate this:

```
/**
 * Test the effect of setting timezone on a {@link SimpleDateFormat}. Apparently,
 * <code>f.setTimezone()</code> sets the input timezone, and default timezone sets
 * the output timezone.
 *
 */
@Test
public void testTimezoneSettingOnSimpleDateFormat() throws ParseException {
    /* *********** test parsing *********** */
    log.info("********** test parsing **********");
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String d = "2018-08-08 12:34:56";

    log.info("Trying to parse the date string: {}", d);
    Date result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 12:34 UTC: {}", result);

    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 12:34 UTC: {}", result);

    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    result = f.parse(d);
    log.info("The result should be 10:34 UTC: {}", result);

    /* ********** test formatting ********** */
    log.info("********** test formatting **********");
    // given
    SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    // construct a date to represent this moment
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.of(2018, 11, 16, 10, 22, 22, 0, ZoneOffset.of("+0100"));
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai")); // GMT+8, so Madrid+7
    // when you construct a date without timezone, it will be the timezone of system/default!
    Date nowDate = new Date(now.toEpochSecond() * 1000);
    log.info("The constructed date is: {}", nowDate); // Fri Nov 16 17:22:22 CST 2018

    // now formatter timezone is Madrid
    f2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    // now default timezone is Asia/Shanghai

    // when
    String result2 = f2.format(nowDate);

    // then
    log.info("The result should be 10:22: {}", result2); // 2018-11-16T10:22:22+01:00


    log.info("Conclusion: the formatter's timezone sets the timezone of input; the application/default " +
            "timezone sets the timezone of output. ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Instant getInstantNow() {
        Clock utcClock = Clock.systemUTC();
        //ZoneId myTZ = ZoneId.of("Brazil/East");       
        return Instant.now(utcClock).minusSeconds(10800);   
        //Instant in = Instant.now(utcClock);
        //return in.atZone(myTZ);   
    }

    public static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeNow() {
        ZonedDateTime nowBrasil = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Brazil/East"));
        return LocalDateTime.from(nowBrasil);
    }

    public static LocalDate getLocalDateNow() {
        ZonedDateTime nowBrasil = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Brazil/East"));
        return LocalDate.from(nowBrasil);
    }
```

Comment: So you suggest using Java 8 Time. Totally correct. I think I may change one day... but Spring seems to use SimpleDateFormatter in Jackson, which is the purpose of my simulation here... I am not sure..