# Configure Spring REST endpoint to ignore appending timezone when serializing date fields in response objects

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jackson

I have an endpoint in my spring boot application that returns date ranges.
The backend is PostgreSQL and date columns in my database are defined as **without timezone**

I would like my endpoint in my spring boot application return the dates as is.

Currently, the dates get serialized with the timezone for the spring boot server.

Is there a way to configure my spring boot application to selectively ignore appending timezone data to the dates when serializing them?

the entity class is as below

```
public class Period{
   private Date startdate;
   private Date enddate;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Entity where the date columns are used?

Comment: hi @Sebastian, I have included the Entity in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use more modern `java.time` package, rather than outdated `java.util.Date`.

In your case, you can use `LocalDate` (or `LocalDateTime`). It does not contain any information about time-zone nor offset, and by default it is serialized to ISO 8601 format like `2019-12-31T23:59:59`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a similar post with an elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930920/1931756)

just adding the desired timezone as below to you `application.properties` file will do solve it

```
spring.jackson.time-zone= America/Sao_Paulo
```